# Let be $G=(V,E)$ a graph and let $U$ be a set containing circles in $G$. Is $(U, E)$ a matroid?

Tags: graph-theory, matroids

Let be $G=(V,E)$ a graph and let be $U$ a set containing circles in $G$. Is $(U, E)$ a matroid? 
I draw an easy graph (undirected) and checked this property.  It does not hold for my example.

My example was like a graph with nodes $V=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and edges $E=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ with the circles $\{a,b,d\}$ , $\{a,b,c,e\}$ and $\{d,e,c\} $ and this one would be a matroid if  the empty set would not be missing. So the statement is not true or am I missing something? Any Help is much appreciated.

Comment: The pair $(U,E)$: which is the ground set, I guess $E$? which is the independent sets, I guess $U$? You should say $U\subset V$ or $U\subset E$. I only know the graphic matroid which the independent set is the set which contains no circle.

Comment: E is the ground set and U the independent set. Your last statement I know as definition of a graphic matroid. But for this case the problem should be the empty set, or?

Comment: @JohnDoe How did you come to this conclusion? If $U$ represents the independent sets, doesn't it need to be closed under taking subsets? And what would be the bases of this matroid?

Comment: @Kevin Long my example does not work, that is why I guess (U,E) is no matroid. It would be nice if someone just could tell me if I am right..

Comment: @JohnDoe Oh, if you're asking if it's *not* a matroid, then it's not. You showed it yourself.

Comment: This question needs some clarification. What is meant by "is the pair $(U,E)$ a matroid"? Moreover, if the answer to the last question is "is the set $U$ the set of independent sets of some matroid", then the example given contains an error. The independent sets of a matroid form a **simplicial complex** (any subset of an independent set is independent), and moreover this simplicial complex is **pure**, i.e., the inclusion-maximal elements all have the same cardinality. The example in the original question  fails on both fronts, even if we add the empty set to the mix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subset $C$ of circles (which I will call cycles here) of a graph $G$ cannot form the independent sets of a matroid. The reason for this is that the empty set is always an independent set (see the first axiom [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid#Independent_sets)) of a matroid while it is always (trivially) acyclic in $G$.

What happens if we append the empty set to $C$? Well, if $C' := C \cup \{\emptyset\}$ are the independent sets of a matroid then they form a simplicial complex (every subset of set in $C'$ is also in $C'$). In particular, for every edge $e$ in some cycle in $C'$ we have $\{e\} \in C'$. But since $C'$ is a collection of cycles of $G$ it follows that $e$ is a loop in $G$. But this implies that every cycle in $C'$ is a loop. So any matroid whose independent sets are of the form $C'$ is the trivial matroid (whose only basis is the empty set) together with some loops, that is, the uniform matroid $\mathcal{U}_{0,n}$ where $n$ is the number of loops.

On the other hand, the cycles of any graph $G$ do yield a matroid (the [*cycle matroid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid#Matroids_from_graph_theory) of $G$) whose circuits are the cycles of $G$ and whose independent sets (respectively, bases) are the forests (spanning forests) of $G$.

Answer (score -1):

From definition of matroid,

> Every subset of member of independent set is also an independent set.

So, if $U$ are set of independent sets, then for $A \in U$, one has $\{e\} \subset A$ is also independent set, but it is obvious not true because $\{e\}$ contains no circle.

Comment: This argument is technically incorrect. Consider the case when all edges of $G$ are loops, i.e., cycles (circles) of length 1.

Comment: No, the cycle in graph is a path of edges and vertices wherein a vertex is reachable from itself. So, one edge is not cycle. But $\{a,a\}$ is a cycle. Of course, you can say a special edge which has only one vertex, it is really a loop.

Comment: If $e = \{a,a\}$ is an edge in $G$ then the path $a,e,a$ is a closed walk in $G$ from $a$ to $a$, so it is a cycle. Loops are precisely the cycles of length one.